# User given a login prompt when closing Word documents after viewing them in IE7

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, permissions, internet-explorer, microsoft-office

When using IE7 to view Word documents on our CRM system (an ASP.NET 2.0 application running on Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6 and using Windows authenticaton) I'm finding that a prompt appears when the user closes the document. The Word document is originally opened by clicking a link in the CRM system.

Are there permissions that I can set on the folder containing the Word documents to prevent this prompt? I've already tried only allowing the Read permission for the Users group (I've left Administrators with Full Control.)

If there's another solution to this without using permissions please let me know.

**UPDATE:**

I ran Fiddler as suggested by JD and here is the output from the two responses after the request for the document. The first seems to be a DAV response and the second is the authentication request. How do I prevent the DAV response and just return the .doc on the server?

```
OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
Translate: f
User-Agent: Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider Protocol Discovery
Host: <REMOVED>
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
X-NovINet: v1.2

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Feb 2010 13:37:36 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Ranges: none
DASL: <DAV:sql>
DAV: 1, 2
Public: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, DELETE, PUT, POST, COPY, MOVE, MKCOL, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, LOCK, UNLOCK, SEARCH
Allow: OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, COPY, PROPFIND, SEARCH, LOCK, UNLOCK
Cache-Control: private

------------------------------------------------------------------
OPTIONS /docs/ZONE%20100-105.doc HTTP/1.1
Translate: f
User-Agent: Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider Protocol Discovery
Host: <REMOVED>
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
X-NovINet: v1.2

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 83
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="<REMOVED>"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 18 Feb 2010 13:37:36 GMT

------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I found a potential workaround for the problem via this post: http://forums.iis.net/p/1149091/1868317.aspx. I moved all of the documents that are being requested into a folder outside of the web root, and created a virtual directory for it (also outside of the web root).

When I followed a link to one of the documents in IE and then closed the document I wasn't presented with a login prompt.

I should point out that I'm not using FPSE, unlike the person in the forum post.

Ideally I don't want to have to put the documents in a separate virtual directory, but this is the simplest solution I've found so far.

Comment: your question is a bit unclear -- how exactly are the documents being "viewed"?

Comment: They are being browsed in IE.

Comment: What sort of login prompt? The standard windows domain login dialogue? A screenshot might be handy. Also are you sure the prompt comes up at the point of closing the document, or could it appear before (or at the same time) but Word just appears over it so it isn't visible until Word gets closed or minimised? Also, how is the document referenced in the HTML? A straight "A HREF=...", that with a TARGET="" attribute, a javascript link in HREF="", an onclick event defined in the tag, ...?. Some example HTML may help if you could add that to your question.

Comment: Yes it is the standard windows domain login - title is "Connect to <domain>" and the rest is "The server <domain> at <domain> requires a username and password."

The prompt appears after clicking close button on the window, and the window doesn't close while the login dialog is present.

The link is a straight `href` with `target="_blank`. The URL is relative, I will try an absolute URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known problem with Office products.  In a nutshell they have tight integration with SharePoint and will make calls to the server that hosted the document to see if it has SharePoint installed.  These calls are what is causing the login prompt.

You can use a tool like Fiddler to actually see the traffic to your server from Word.

We used ISAPI_Rewrite to block the requests, which solved the problem.

Comment: So is the problem in IE and there is nothing I can do on the server to prevent it? Was this problem introduced in IE7?

Comment: No, it is Word doing the call.  It has been around since Office 2003.

Comment: We don't use ISAPI_Rewrite. I'll consider that as a last resort. I think I'll probably convert the documents to HTML before I reach that point!